# Почта @live.ru и WLM

Tags: email

Пользуюсь почтовой программой [Windows Live Mail 2012](//filehippo.com/download_windows_live_mail/) (Build 16.4.3528.0331). Причиной её выбора когда-то стало то, что только она умела работать с майкросовтовской почтой @live.ru по тамошнему http-протоколу, но в целом она меня устраивает по всем критериям: не смешивает почтовые ящики в кучу, но позволяет настраивать быстрые представления. Имеется группировка по темам. И интерфейс удобный.

Но некоторое время назад получил несколько писем от майкросовта о том, что доступ к live.ru-почте из неё будет работать только до конца июня:

> Мы заметили, что вы подключаетесь к учетной записи Outlo‍ok‍.‍com с помощью приложения "Почта Windows Live 2012". Обратите внимание, что "Почта Windows Live 2012" не поддерживает технологии синхронизации, которые используются в новой службе Outlo‍ok‍.‍com. **После обновления учетной записи, которое произойдет в конце июня, вы не сможете ни отправлять, ни получать электронные сообщения в учетной записи Outlo‍ok‍.‍com с помощью приложения "Почта Windows Live 2012".** Не волнуйтесь, вы в любое время можете войти в свою учетную запись Outlo‍ok‍.‍com через веб-браузер и по-прежнему сможете обращаться ко всем данным, которые сейчас находятся в приложении "Почта Windows Live 2012".

В качестве решения в письме предлагается обновиться до десятки (у меня Win7) или получить годовую подписку на Office 365:

> Если вы работаете в Windows 7, то для использования приложения "Почта" можно выполнить обновление до более новой версии Windows. Если вы не хотите выполнять обновление, можете работать со своей учетной записью через веб-браузер или воспользоваться бесплатной годовой подпиской на Off‍ice 3‍6‍5 персональный и использовать Outlook 2016 для подключения к учетной записи.* Outlook 2016 работает на операционных системах Windows 7, Windows 8/8.1 и Windows 10.
>
> * Необходимо активировать до 15 октября 2016 г. Действительно для пользователей, впервые оформивших подписку на Off‍ice 3‍6‍5. Необходимо указать данные кредитной карты. Вы можете отменить подписку в любое время на странице www.office.com/myaccount. Ознакомиться с полным текстом условий можно здесь.

Можно ли как-то продолжить пользоваться через WLM? На какой протокол они перешли - может на самом деле надо просто добавить аккаунт заново с imap? В таком случае, какие настройки следует указывать?

Если на вопрос про WLM ответ отрицательный, то какие бесплатные почтовые программы можно использовать для доступа к почте из Windows 7? И как их настроить?

PS: Убрал из цитат ссылки, т. к. переходы по ним явно отслеживаются.

---

Некоторое время назад почта всё-таки перестала работать... Надо как-то настраивать.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://suse.me/apps/windows-live-mail?platform=28&license=All) можете список похожих программ посмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе [Add your Outlook.com account to another mail app](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-your-Outlook-com-account-to-another-mail-app-73f3b178-0009-41ae-aab1-87b80fa94970)

```
IMAP imap-mail.outlook.com:993
IMAP encryption method SSL

POP pop-mail.outlook.com:995
POP encryption method SSL

SMTP smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
SMTP encryption method TLS
```

При использовании POP требуется дополнительно настроить ящик.

И скриншоты настройки WLM для IMAP:

[image: WLM Settings]